# Icecast - how to show currently playing song on a website

Tags: icecast, winamp

i found a lot of topics on this question, but i didnt get an answer. I'm streaming music to my website using icecast and winamp. Now i want to display the current song that is playing on the website. How can i do that? Thanks!

Comment: The JSON API is reasonably well documented and as you undoubtedly have noticed is referred to in many answers here. What are you specifically looking for beyond "Use the JSON API"? Are you looking for examples? Please explain.

Comment: Yes, i would love to get an example on how to reach server/admin stats and display them on the website (current song). Thanks a lot.

Comment: Following this really simple tutorial (https://linge-ma.ws/update-listeners-track-on-a-website-using-icecast-jsonp-and-jquery/) i have made exatcly what i wanted.